# Problems with hosting reportviewer reports vs2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I am having a prob with a report in vs2010:

> An error occurred during local report processing.
>   The definition of the report 'Report1.rdlc' is invalid.
>   An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have added the other reportviewer dlls to the bin but I am struggling to find this one.

I am hosting with cyberyhost pro if anybody has experience of that.

Also reports are in local mode.

I have tried to extract the dll from the reportviewer distributable setup but I dont know what I am doing :) and failed miserably.

Thanks in advance 
Roger

Answer (score 1):

I turns out that cyberhost needed to install reportviewer on the server. I didnt have a hope in hell of fixing this problem myself.

Thanks for the views though.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the DLL in the assembly cache.

Open Add Reference and navigate to:
(Windows/assembly/Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel).

Choose the folder that starts with 10.0.0.0 and select the DLL.